# re-using integer pointer in C array stack with `realloc()`

Tags: c, stack, realloc

I have an array stack implemented in C which I'm pretty sure is correct. I am confused about the following.

I can for example, do something like:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    stack S = Stack();
    int *X = malloc(sizeof(int)*3) ;
    int *Y = malloc(sizeof(int)*5) ;
    int i;
    int *M;

    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        X[i] = i*i;
    }
    X[2] = 10*10;

    Push(S, X);

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        Y[i] = 2*i*i;
    }
    Y[4] = 2*10*10;

    Push(S, Y);

    M = Pop(S);
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) { 
        printf("%d - ", M[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    M = Pop(S);
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) { 
        printf("%d - ", M[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

which prints out this:

```
0 - 2 - 8 - 18 - 200 -
0 - 1 - 100 -
```

but I cannot do this:

```
    #include "stack.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void) {
    stack S = Stack();
    int *X = malloc(sizeof(int)*3) ;
    int i;
    int *M;

    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        X[i] = i*i;
    }
    X[2] = 10*10;

    Push(S, X);

    X = realloc(X, sizeof(int) * 5);

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        X[i] = 2*i*i;
    }
    X[4] = 2*10*10;

    Push(S, X);

    M = Pop(S);
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) { 
        printf("%d - ", M[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    M = Pop(S);
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) { 
        printf("%d - ", M[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

which prints out:

```
0 - 2 - 8 - 18 - 200 -
0 - 1610612736 - 0 -
```

why am I unable to use the pointer X for multiple push steps on to the stack? Am I just using realloc incorrectly or can this not be done in this case?

Comment: What is `Push(x, y)`?

Comment: Please: a [mcve].

Comment: How does your array stack work? Seems like you keep the pointers to the beginning of your arrays in the stack. Not the content of the arrays. You will need to pass the size of the array to Push() and Pop() to actually store the content in the stack.

Comment: @bratner I converted an integer stack into an array stack, it is based on a linked list.. do you have a link to an example stack that stores the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when doing this:

```
X = realloc(X, sizeof(int) * 5);
```

the previous value of `X` cannot be relied on (it could remain the same if the system is able to resize the current memory area, but that's not guaranteed at all), so if you store pointers in your stack you cannot use `realloc`: you get *undefined behaviour* when `X` memory gets moved.

Comment: yes, I am getting this behaviour..all items in the stack stay the same.. could you please tell me the appropriate way to deal with this then?

Comment: you would have to update the values of `X` in your stack. I would create a special realloc method which stores the previous value & replaces it by the value returned by `realloc` on your stack.

Comment: Here is a quote from 'man realloc':
_ If  the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be initialized. _

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre realloc() AFAIK will not lose your data if you increasing the size of the allocation. The "unrealiability" of realloc() is because the pointer may change its value.

Comment: @bratner not saying otherwise. I'm not saying that `realloc` is not reliable, just that the value can change

Comment: why is it also not right to free(X), then malloc() to the right size?

Comment: @dimebucker91 it's the same problem. you have to alloc, copy then free: 2 separate addresses, that's now guaranteed...

Answer (score 2):

So you asked to allocate the memory `int *X = malloc(sizeof(int)*3)`.
The machine went ahead and gave you some RAM, X is now has a value of `0x1000`.
You went ahead and pushed it to your stack by `Push(S, X)`. Now your stack has `0x1000` on top.
Then you asked to re-allocate X with `X = realloc(X, sizeof(int) * 5)`. Just like @jean-françois-fabre said, X may change. Assume it did change and now all your previous values in the X buffer were copied by realloc() to a new address contained in X, lets say it is `0x2000`. So you push it again to your stack. So the stack S looks like this

- `0x2000`  - this is a valid address allocated for 5 ints.
- `0x1000`  - this is an **invalid** address which should be ignored.

So when you do the second `Pop(S)` you get an invalid address which is not allocated to you and may assume that everything in it is garbage.

Comment: i understand the problem now.. which answers the original question, but I don't know how to create a special realloc method to solve this problem if i want to use the stack dynamically

Comment: @dimebucker91 You just cannot mix this simple Stack with realloc() like this. Your Stack just looks after variables, it is not a memory manager. Building functionality to make it able to handle re-allocating blocks isn't impossible but you won't have a simple Stack at the end, you'll have a memory block manager.